# How to split a data frame in the order I want?

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a data frame df like this

```
df 
x     y   id
10   5     2
12   10    2
15   0     1
```

I want to split by the id. I used `split(df, df$id)` and I get

```
x   y   id
15  0   1
```

and

```
x   y    id
10  5    2
12  10   2
```

But I want the one with id=2 to come before than the one with id =1
So basically I want the output to be

```
x     y     id
10   5      2
12   10     2
```

and

```
x    y    id
15   0    1
```

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation of `split()`, *The components of the list are named by the levels of `f` (after converting to a factor ...)*. `f` is the second parameter to `split()`. So, the chunks appear in the order of the factor levels after splitting.

The [OP has requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420629/how-to-split-a-data-frame-in-the-order-i-want/43447864#comment73924054_43420689) that the chunks should be returned in the same order as they appear in `df`. This can be achieved conveniently with the `fct_inorder()` function of Hadley's `forcats` package:

```
split(df, forcats::fct_inorder(factor(df$id)))
#$`2`
#   x  y id
#1 10  5  2
#2 12 10  2
#
#$`1`
#   x y id
#3 15 0  1
```

Note, that

- `id` itself remains unchanged. `fct_inorder()` is only used for defining the split.
- the additional call to `factor()` is only required because `id` is of type `integer`.

**Edit** This can also be achieved without any packages:

```
split(df, factor(df$id, levels = unique(df$id)))
```

Comment: Is there any other way I can achieve this without using any package?

Comment: @Taliman It's possible but not as easy to remember. See my edit.

Comment: This is great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just switch the order of the elements in the list.

```
Sdf = split(df, df$id)
Sdf = Sdf[c(2,1)]

$`2`
   x  y id
1 10  5  2
2 12 10  2

$`1`
   x y id
3 15 0  1
```

You could also use `rev` (reverse)

```
Sdf = rev(Sdf)
```

Comment: Thanks. But for my problem I cannot use reverse as the data frame is generated in a loop and there are times when I want the data to from id =1 to id =2.

Comment: I cannot use reverse for my problem because I sometimes want the id's to follow order like go from id=1 to id=2

Comment: OK.  But if you can specify the order,  you can use the first method.

Comment: I was wondering why split function splits the data from id =1 to id =2 even though the data has id=2 first? Do you know the reason?

Comment: @Taliman The documentation of `split()` says in the _Value_ section: _The components of the list are named by the levels of `f` (after converting to a factor ...)_ `f` is the second parameter to `split()`. So, the chunks appear in the order of the factor levels.

Comment: Is there any way I can change this factor level so that the splitting is done just as the data is presented?